# download the zip file of the layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to download the .zip file of the layer.
I tried this command to get the location of the third party layer that I plan to use in my lambda function.
But the location URL is too long and I get 403 Forbidden error.

```
#  aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p310-requests:9"
{
    "Content": {
        "Location": "https://prod-04-2014-layers.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/snapshots/770693421928/Klayers-p310-requests-a-long-url-here",
        "CodeSha256": "1vMDze/FCL0FyxN4ccNqUkK0JZM4i5wmMfZXYMY42LQ=",
        "CodeSize": 888173
    },
    "LayerArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p310-requests",
    "LayerVersionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p310-requests:9",
    "Description": "requests==2.31.0 | 147e396d4e434d6fb48e42bd7aa6f1453b3fd1b572be35b083ad06eb28f3e959",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-03-01T02:06:11.454+0000",
    "Version": 9,
    "CompatibleRuntimes": [
        "python3.10"
    ],
    "LicenseInfo": "Apache 2.0",
    "CompatibleArchitectures": [
        "x86_64"
    ]
}
```

How to download the zip file of the layer provided by
someone else?

Comment: you just need S3 read access to that location so that you can download the layer.

Comment: A `403` error means `Access Denied`. It is not related to the length of the URL.